# How do I prove $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

Here is how I proved this exercise.

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is a group isomorphism.

Set $\phi(1,0)=(a,b,c)$ and $\phi(0,1)=(d,e,f)$.

Then, it can be viewed as $span(\{(a,b,c),(d,e,f)\}) = \mathbb{R}^3$. This is obviously false. (Is my argument correct?)

However, is there another way to prove this not using linear algebra, just using group theory?

Comment: Hint: How many elements are in the basis?

Comment: @REr I know that.. I'm just asking whether there is a direct way to prove this just using group theory

Comment: You mean $\mathbb Z^3$ (not $\mathbb R^3$)?

Comment: @TroyWoo No I meant $\mathbb{R}^3$. This was on a graduate school entrance exam.. Should not use module argument

Comment: @Rubertos as you really meant $\;\Bbb R^3\;$, then you must explain how you mix both $\;\Bbb Z^3\;,\;\;\Bbb R^3\;$ in any attempt to prove what you want, which seems to be independent of what happens in $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc As I commented on hunter's answer, isn't it sufficient to show that (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) are linear combinations of (a,b,c) and (d,e,f) over either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? And this is satisfied by the bijectivity of $\phi$.

Comment: I don't get which part of my argument is not rigorous..

Comment: @Rubertos How, or from what, do you deduce that if $\;\phi\;$ is a hypothetical isomorphism, then  Span$\,\{\phi(1,0)\,,\,\phi(0,1)\}\;$ **has** to be a generator set of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ as a linear space (over itself, I presume) ? This much you should detail in your answer, imo.

Comment: @Timbuc I see. I was just wondering if my argument is wrong (rather than incomplete). Thank you..

Comment: @Rubertos Well, for sure I'd say it is incomplete as it doesn't include an explanation of the above details. On the other hand I wonder how difficult could it be to prove that a **free** basis of the free abelian group $\;\Bbb Z^n\;$ is *also* a basis of the linear space $\;\Bbb R^n_{\Bbb R}\;$ ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $G= {\mathbb Z}^3$ and $H={\mathbb Z}^2$, then $|G/2G|=8$ and $|H/2H|=4$, so $G/2G \not\cong H/2H$ and hence $G \not\cong H$.

Comment: Beat me to it, though I was going to comment that any homomorphic immage of $\;\Bbb Z^2\;$ is generated by two elements at most, whereas there's an homomorphic image of $\;\Bbb Z^3\;$ which *requires* at least three generators. +1

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}^3$ is an isomorphism then so is $\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{Z}^3\to\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Show that some linear combination $\phi^{-1}(1,0,0)$, $\phi^{-1}(0,1,0)$ and $\phi^{-1}(0,0,1)$ is zero and therefore $\phi^{-1}$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is basically correct, but isn't so precise. The more precise way to say your same argument, which you probably haven't run into the language for in your course yet, is that $\phi$ cannot be an isomorphism after tensoring with $\mathbb{R}$ for dimension reasons, and thus already cannot be an isomorphism.

You may find one of the other arguments here more useful, just because it's easier to write without having to define too precisely what you call "viewing" the map in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Why is it not precise? There exsits (n,m) such that $(1,0,0)=n(a,b,c)+m(d,e,f)$. And same for $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Hence, considering these two tuples as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, they span.

Comment: That new wording is perfectly precise.